# Convert yuv video to png frames using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, png, frame, yuv

I want to convert a yuv video to png frames using `ffmpeg`.

The command I use is

`/root/bin/ffmpeg -i pirkagia_max_vid_qual_one.yuv -s 720x576 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f image2 one/image-%3d.png`

I get the following response:

`ffmpeg version git-2015-08-07-8015150 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      54. 30.100 / 54. 30.100
  libavcodec     56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 32.100 /  5. 32.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7fffe8e84760] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7fffe8e84310] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[rawvideo @ 0x3aaf160] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, -4 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
pirkagia_max_vid_qual_one.yuv: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pirkagia_max_vid_qual_one.yuv':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, -4 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, image2, to 'one/image-%3d.png':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the [rawvideo demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) needs additional information. Since there appears to be no header in your inputs specifying the video parameters you must specify them in order to be able to decode the data correctly. Example:

```
ffmpeg -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 720x576 -framerate 25 -i …
```

Also, `yuv420p` is incompatible for the PNG encoder, so you can remove that as an output option and an appropriate pixel format will be auto-selected.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os

num = 1
video_name = ['out.yuv']
short = ['yuv']

for i in range(num):
    saveroot = 'images/' + short[i]
    savepath = 'images/' + short[i] + '/im%03d.yuv'

    if not os.path.exists(saveroot):
        os.makedirs(saveroot)

    print('ffmpeg -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1024 -i ' + 'videos_crop/' + video_name[i] +  ' ' + savepath)

    os.system('ffmpeg -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1024 -i ' +  'videos_crop/' + video_name[i] +  ' ' + savepath)
```